# Future Call Order and Custom Executor

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I am running into an issue where the executor does not shut down and the second last future call executes after the last future call and the program does not terminate.

```
  import java.util.concurrent.Executors

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

  val customExecutor: ExecutorService =
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(serviceConfig.serviceConf.numberOfThreads)
  implicit val customExecutionContext: ExecutionContext =
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))

  val remainingRecords = data.foldLeft(Seq.empty[Int]) {
    case (a, b) =>
      fetchAllData()
        .foldLeft(c) {
          case (a, file) =>
            sendInBatches(a)
        }
  }

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def sendData(res: Seq[Int]) = {
    ...
    futureCall() map { result =>
      logger.info(
        s"Successfully Executed"
      )
    }
    sendData()
  }

  if (remainingRecords.nonEmpty) {
    futureCall() map { result =>
      logger.info(
        s"Successfully executed the remaining"
      )
      customExecutor.shutdown()
    }
  }
```

I get the log "Successfully executed the remaining" then "Successfully Executed" and the application does not stop even when i manually shutdown the executor.

Comment: Can you fix int indentation? It is hard to tell if some suspicious things in this code are in logic or just typos when in comes to `{}`.

Comment: Mateusz Kubuszok, Fixed. Also the  problem that i am trying to solve is stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984343/tail-recursion-use-case-solution-in-scala/60984587#60984587

Answer (score 0):

It is a long shot but this code:

```
def sendData(res: Seq[Int]) =
    {
        ...
      futureCall() map { result =>
      logger.info(
      s"Successfully Executed"
      )
    }
      sendData()
    }
```

NEVER terminates. `executor.shutdown()` prevents new tasks to be scheduled on a thread pool but isn't killing any ongoing tasks, to allow a graceful shutdown. Since this code is running and the task is never ending, executor is waiting for it to finish, and waiting and waiting...

You can try to use `shutdownNow()` and/or make this effectively infinite loop to end if you processed all data by adding some check before recursively calling `sendData()`.

Comment: Please look at the complete scenario. The code you have explained would definitely never terminate. For complete scenario please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60984343/tail-recursion-use-case-solution-in-scala/60984587#60984587